# List attachment details

Tags: powershell, attachments

I have a SharePoint application with many users. Is it possible to get list of all attachments in a list item with user name and date time when the attachment was added using PowerShell commands?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, here is the PowerShell Code:

```
$web = Get-SPWeb -Identity http://sp2010:90
$list = $web.Lists["Resources"]
foreach ($item in $list.Items)
{
    $attachmentCollection = $item.Attachments
    $folder = $web.GetFolder($attachmentCollection.UrlPrefix);
    foreach ($file in $folder.Files)
    {
        Write-Host $item.Title
        Write-Host $file.Name
        Write-Host $file.Author
        Write-Host $file.TimeCreated
    }
}
```